# Connect to Database from Apigee

Tags: database, node.js, api, apigee

Can anyone let me know if it is possible to connect to a Microsoft database from Apigee oncloud? We have a requirement to perform get and post operations from the database.

I tried to search it on internet, but did not get any information.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your license, since you might be able to use Java for this, but this requires a Developer license:
http://apigee.com/docs/developer-vs-edge

My best bet would be to add a thin API layer on top of your database for the CRUD operations. Probably a good idea as well to decrease the latency as much as possible or perform an async operation (if possible) towards the database API. From an architectural point of view the MSSQL database should be 'close' to your backend systems, while your API should be pointing 'outside'. Ensure to secure the connection between your Apigee layer and your Database API layer (firewall, SSL).

Hope this helps.